# How do I set RabbitMQ logging level to debug, really?

Tags: logging, configuration, rabbitmq

I'm trying to figure out how to solve a specific problem with RabbitMQ 3.6.6. In order to gather some more information, I wanted to switch logs to debug level. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the relevant part of `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config`, inspired by [the official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html):

```
[
    {rabbit,
        [
            {log_levels, [{connection, debug}, {queue, debug}]},
            {log,
                [{file, [{level, debug}]},
                {categories,
                    [{connection,
                        [{level, debug}]
                    },
                    {queue,
                        [{level, debug}]
                    }
                    ]
                }]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

However, what I see in the actual logs (after restarting the server) looks nothing like verbose logs. Not only all messages I see are marked only `INFO REPORT` or `ERROR REPORT`, but also when I create a queue, I see only two messages:

> accepting AMQP connection [...]
>
> Mirrored queue [...] in vhost [...]: Adding mirror on node [...]

which doesn't look particularly verbose.

So, how do I set log level to debug in RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that [verbose logging is not that verbose](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/CPly-qlWHTg), after all:

> There's very little debug logging in 3.6.x (or earlier)[...]
>
> In most cases debug logging isn't as useful as Erlang tracing capabilities or a traffic capture

The solution was to move to RabbitMQ 3.8.3, which seems having a bit more logs. Then, the log level can be changed like this with the new configuration format:

```
log.file.level = debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to look into the console logs , if yes , t , you need to configure the console log level as well by adding the additional node as

```
[
{rabbit,
    [
        {log_levels, [{connection, debug}, {queue, debug}]},
        {log,
            [{file, [{level, debug}]},
            {categories,
                [{connection,
                    [{level, debug}]
                },
                {queue,
                    [{level, debug}]
                },
                {console, 
                    [{enabled, true},
                     {level, debug}]
                }
                ]
            }]
        },
    ]
}
```

]

in the config file

Comment: I was looking at the logs in `/var/log/rabbitmq`, not the console logs.